# tinymce spellcheck not found

Tags: javascript, cakephp, tinymce

I have implemented `TinyMCE` successfully in cakephp and now I want to add `spellchecker` but it gives me `404 not found error`. Below is the code I used.

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea.richtext",
    theme: "modern",
    width: 600,
    height: 250,
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink link image lists charmap hr anchor pagebreak",
        "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
        "save table contextmenu directionality emoticons template paste textcolor code spellchecker"
    ],
    spellchecker_rpc_url: 'spellchecker.php',
    browser_spellcheck : true,
    content_css: "css/content.css",
    toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | spellchecker | bold italic underline | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | l      ink image | preview media fullpage | forecolor backcolor emoticons | code",
    style_formats: [
        {title: 'Bold text', inline: 'b'},
        {title: 'Red text', inline: 'span', styles: {color: '#ff0000'}},
        {title: 'Red header', block: 'h1', styles: {color: '#ff0000'}},
        {title: 'Example 1', inline: 'span', classes: 'example1'},
        {title: 'Example 2', inline: 'span', classes: 'example2'},
        {title: 'Table styles'},
        {title: 'Table row 1', selector: 'tr', classes: 'tablerow1'}
    ]
});
```

And error is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE does not come with a spellcheck engine -  this is something you need to install on your server as documented here:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/get-started/spell-checking/

You can rely on...

- Browser's spellcheck
- Open Source Server-side spellcheck
- Commercial Server-side spellcheck

Those options are all reviewed on the page referenced above.

Your error shows you are using the CDN to run TinyMCE but that instance will not have the spellchecker server-side code installed hence your error.  You can indeed run the CDN copy of TinyMCE you just need to install the spelling stuff on your server and setup the `spellchecker_rpc_url` properly.